# Is there a "smoking gun" to distinguish between ConTeXt and plain TeX

Tags: context, plain-tex

I'm writing a tool to streamline some typesetting jobs, and I am having trouble distinguishing between plain Tex and ConTeXt.

LaTeX is straightforward to recognise by the `\documentclass` command (or `\documentstyle` for old documents), however I am struggling to find a "smoking gun" to differentiate ConTeXt source from plain TeX source.

It seems that the `\starttext . . . \stoptext` pair is common in ConTeXt, but not guaranteed.  Is there something better, or a combination of things that are better?

I understand that due to TeX's nature it is impossible write a filter to do this 100% accurately, but 90-95% accuracy will still be a great help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any **`\start...` is good enough** to identify something as ConTeXt and not Plain, if you do not care about old-school AMSTeX files.

If you want complete commands, there are quite a few top-level document delimiters in ConTeXt:

#### The usual document delimiters

- [`\starttext`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/starttext) — load the bodyfont and do all the usual setups, plzkthx
- [`\startdocument`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/start) — used for parametrising documents. See [Abstracting an author list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83629/abstracting-an-author-list).

#### Special page environments

These create individual pages, but of course such a page may constitute an entire document

- [`\startTEXpage`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startTEXpage) — a page that exactly fits the TeX output it contains
- [`\startMPpage`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startMPpage) — a page that exactly fits the MetaPost graphic it contains

#### Parts of the [project system](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Project_structure)

- [`\startcomponent`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startcomponent) — (reusable) product elements
- [`\startproduct`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startproduct) — a product contains multiple components
- [`\startenvironment`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startenvironment) — setups and definitions
- [`\startproject`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startproject) — link products and components to suitable environments

#### Other auxiliary files

- [`\startmodule`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startmodule) — modules and environments are the same, really. In general, though, environments are written *ad hoc*, while modules are written to be reused (by others).
- [`\startxmlsetups`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startxmlsetups) — ConTeXt can take XML as input, and a file with XML setups that tell it how to translate the XML to TeX.

---

Incidentally, LaTeX documents need not contain a `{document}` environment. LaTeX will generate an error if any output is generated before `\begin{document}`, which Context does not; but a document without output can still be valid (compile without error), of course. If you access the primitive `\end` command with `\makeatletter\@@end`, you can end the document without resorting to LaTeX's `\end{document}`.

**Note from Charles** I've made this CW, since by now most of the knowledge it contains comes from the comments below.

Comment: Not quite true. There are more environments that can delimit the body text from the setup area. These are valid ConTeXt documents: `\startdocument FooBar \stopdocument`, `\startcomponent * FooBar \stopcomponent` or `\startproduct * FooBar \stopproduct`.

Comment: @Marco: I'll delete this answer shortly, and maybe undelete it if I fix it.

Comment: No need to delete it. Since the OP asked for 90% accurately, it would be fine to test for the delimiters I mentioned additionally to `starttext`. And rephrase the first paragraph accordingly.

Comment: Any '\start...' is good enough to differentiate between plain and ConTeXt, if you do not care about old-school amsTeX files.

Comment: LaTeX doesn't really undefine `\bye`, it just doesn't define it (LaTeX isn't based on plain). You could also close the document with `\stop` or `\@@end`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for reminding me that not only `\enddocument` can end a document - I've changed the answer.  And that `\bye` is not a Tex primitive - I should have said `\end`.

Comment: Point 3: The module system predates the `startdocument` command. It's a rather new command added in the end of 2011 as a more flexible alternative to `starttext` which simplifies the use of document-related variables. I'm not aware that it's obsolete. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @Marco from Hans Hagen: "ah, i can remove that test because i don't think that nowadays anyone is using startdocument (old functionality to build styles for letters, stickers, etc)" http://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg28002.html - but looking that message he may have made a typo

Comment: Apparently he introduced a new command with the same name as the old one a few years later (see [beta announcement](http://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg59003.html)).

Comment: Keep in mind that ConTeXt has a multi-lingual interface. So, if I use the Dutch or the German or the French interface, none of the above commands will be there!

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, vim uses the following logic to classify files that have a `.tex` extension.

- Ignore all lines at the beginning of the file that start with a comment.
- Search the next 1000 lines for the following patterns:

  ```
  let lpat = 'documentclass\>\|usepackage\>\|begin{\|newcommand\>\|renewcommand\>'
  let cpat = 'start\a\+\|setup\a\+\|usemodule\|enablemode\|enableregime\|setvariables\|useencoding\|usesymbols\|stelle\a\+\|verwende\a\+\|stel\a\+\|gebruik\a\+\|usa\a\+\|imposta\a\+\|regle\a\+\|utilisemodule\>'
  ```
- If the file contains either of the patterns, classify it with LaTeX or ConTeXt.
- Otherwise, classify it as `g:tex_flavor` (which defaults to plain TeX, but can be overridden by the user).

Source: `s:FtTex()` function in `filetypes.vim`