# ConTeXt Project Structure: Add metadata to component

Tags: macros, context, document-configuration

I am setting up a project structure for a new journal and I want to use a structure like the one in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83769/32018). However, instead of using `document:start` I tried `\startsetups component:start`, but no results.

My structure looks like this:

- test.tex

```
\startproject *
\environment test_env

\product test_prod

\stopproject
```

- test_env.tex

```
\startenvironment *

\setuphead
    [section]
    [textstyle=\em]

\startsetups component:start
  \startalignment[middle]
    {\bfa\setupinterlinespace 
    This should appear somewhere!
     \endgraf}
    \blank[big]
   \stopalignment
\stopsetups

\stopenvironment
```

- test_prod.tex

```
\startproduct *
\project test

\component test_comp

\stopproduct
```

- test_comp.tex

```
\startcomponent *
\product test_prod
%\project test

\section{Test}

Blabla


\stopcomponent
```

Comment: That's because there is no `component:start`.  You could add `\directsetup{component:start}` before every `\startcomponent` or more programatically `\prependvalue{startcomponent}{\directsetup{component:start}}` (and likewise `\appendvalue{stopcomponent}{\directsetup{component:stop}}`).

Comment: Where can I learn about these things? It's not really clear to me why the mechanism works with `\startdocument` but not with `\startcomponent`. For me this looks similar enough.

Comment: I just [grepped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) the ConTeXt source tree for `component:start` and nothing came up.  Then I also looked at the definition of [`\startcomponent`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/c49d2942bae7074f3bd4c04b6ee895cee1697ca3/tex/context/base/mkiv/file-job.mkvi#L164-L182) to find that there also isn't any other setup code called before.

Comment: Should I post my comments as an answer?

Comment: Yes, please. ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not `component:start`.  The idea is that you only set metadata for the whole document once when you place `\startdocument`.  If you still want to insert your setups before `\startcomponent` you can write

```
\directsetup{component:start}
\startcomponent
```

or more programmatically

```
\prependvalue{startcomponent}{\directsetup{component:start}}
```

Of course this has to be placed before the first `\startcomponent`.